# Compose world-crossing async functions with bind

Tags: f#, monad-transformers, f#+

I have a sample railway pipeline that works well:

```ml
open FSharpPlus

let funA n =
    if n < 10 then Ok n
    else Error "not less than 10"

let funB n =
    if n < 5 then Ok (n, n * 2)
    else Error "not less than 5"

let funC n = // int -> Result<(int * int), string>
    n
    |> funA
    >>= funB // it works
```

But when I want to turn the `funB` to an async function, I got a compilation error. Logically it shouldn't be different. Same output/input... What's wrong?

What should be done to make it work?!

```ml
open FSharpPlus

let funA n =
    if n < 10 then Ok n
    else Error "not less than 10"

let funB n = async {
    if n < 5 then return Ok (n, n * 2)
    else return Error "not less than 5" }

let funC n = // int -> Async<Result<(int * int), string>>
    n
    |> funA
    >>= funB // compile error
```

Comment: Look at the type of operator `>>=`. What is the type of its second argument? Does it match the type of `funB`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Same output/input... What's wrong?

No, they don't have the same output/input.

If you look at the type of `(>>=)` it's something like `'Monad<'T> -> ('T -> 'Monad<'U>) -> 'Monad<'U>` which is a fake signature of a generic bind operation, overloaded for Monads in general. In your first example the Monad is `Result<_,'TError>`, so your first example could be re-written as:

```
let funC n = // int -> Result<(int * int), string>
    n
    |> funA
    |> Result.bind funB
```

The signature of `Result.bind` is `('T -> Result<'U,'TError>) -> Result<'T,'TError> -> Result<'U,'TError>`. This makes sense, if you think about it. It's like applying the substitution `Monad<_>` with `Result<_,'TError>` and you have the arguments flipped that's why we use `|>`.

Then your functions are both `int -> Result<_,'TError>` so types match, and it makes sense (and it works).

Now, moving to your second code fragment, the function `funB` has a different signature, it has `Async<Result<_,'TError>>` so now types don't match. And it also makes sense, you can't use the bind implementation of `Result` for an `Async`.

So, what's the solution?

The easiest solution is don't use bind, at least not for 2 monads. You can "lift" your first function to `Async` and use `async.Bind`, with the generic `>>=` or a standard async workflow, but inside it you'll have to use a manual `match` to bind the results to the second function.

The other approach is more interesting, but also more complex to understand, it consists in using an abstraction called Monad Transformers:

```
open FSharpPlus.Data

let funC n = // int -> Result<(int * int), string>
    n
    |> (funA >> async.Return >> ResultT)
    >>= (funB >> ResultT)
    |> ResultT.run
```

So, what we do here is we "lift" the `funA` function to `Async`, then we wrap it in `ResultT` which is a monad transformer for `Result`, so it has a bind operation that takes care of binding on the outer monad as well, in our case `Async`.

Then we simply wrap `funB` into `ResultT` and at the very end of the function we unwrap from `ResultT` with `Result.run`.

For more examples on layered monads in F#, [see these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23+monad-transformers)

There are other approaches, some libraries provide some "magic workflows" which uses ad-hoc overloading to combine monads with composed monads (aka layered monads), so you write less code, but it's not as easy to reason about the types, since the overloads don't follow any substitution rule, you'll have to look at the source code to understand what's happening.

Note: Coding like this is a good exercise, but in real life consider using exceptions as well to not overcomplicate the code.

Comment: Thank you Gustavo for your great explanations. Everything makes sens now.
I thought that the importance is that the output of funA should be the same as the input of funB, no matter the output of funB. I had misunderstood the principles.
Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: Now I see where the confusion came from. Yes, that sentence is true when doing normal function composition, but when binding monads you have to check that monads are the same.